# Как прибавить к 00000000 единицу

Tags: python

```
passCode = 00000000
isConnected = 'false'
def get_pass(passCode, isConnected):
    while isConnected == 'false':
        print('Пробуем пароль: ' + str(passCode))
        passCode = passCode + 1
        

get_pass(passCode, isConnected)
```

*вывод*:

```
Пробуем пароль: 1
```

*надо*:

```
Пробуем пароль: 00000001
```

Comment: Для начала нужно понять разницу между строкой и числом.

Comment: И между строкой и логическим значением...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще заполнить слева число нулями до нужной длины (align/pad).

Например через метод строки [str.zfill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
for i in range(5):
    print(str(i).zfill(8))

# 00000000
# 00000001
# 00000002
# 00000003
# 00000004
```

---

Еще можно это сделать через форматирование строки. В этом случае после `:` первым символом указывается заполнитель, а вторым длина.

Используя f-string:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(f'{i:08}')
```

Используя `str.format`:

```
for i in range(5):
    print('{:08}'.format(i))
```

Comment: Формат правильней